# How to write a test to specify the format of a http request in ruby?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, httparty, fakeweb

I am writing a gem and I want to check that it is performing an http request with the parameters , headers and content that its supposed to pass. How do I write a unit test.

I am using httparty to do the request, I am also using fakeweb to test actions after the response.

Comment: "How do I write a unit test" is a little vague. Do you need help with rspec syntax? Do you need to know how to set up rspec in a gem environment? Do you want guidance in the TDD or BDD process? Perhaps some code or initial attempts would be a good place to start the discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using webmock and include the stub request that should be created:

In your Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'webmock'
end
```

In your spec:

```
stub_request(:post, 
             "https://external.api.com")
             .with(:body => {:message => {:foo => 'bar'}}, 
                  :headers => {'Accept'=>'application/json'})
```

Comment: actually, you should thanks @juandebravo ;) I just edited the answer.